# How to define AM_CONDITIONAL and AC_DEFINE based on PKG_CHECK_MODULES result?

Tags: sh, autotools, autoconf, automake, pkg-config

I am trying to write a `configure.ac` file to do these tasks:

1. The `configure` script should accept a `--with-libuv` parameter.
2. A variable `with_libuv` should be set to either `yes`, `no` or `check` (with `check` being the default value when nothing was passed on the command line).
3. When `with_libuv == "yes"` a mandatory PKG_CHECK_MODULES check for `libuv >= 1.9.0` should be done and `HAVE_LIBUV = 1` should be set on success (On error `configure` should abort).
4. When `with_libuv == "no"` nothing should be checked,
5. When `with_libuv == "false"` an optional PKG_CHECK_MODULES check (for the same library as in 3.) should be done and `HAVE_LIBUV` should be set to either `0` or `1` accordingly.
6. If `with_libuv != "no" && HAVE_LIBUV == 1` AC_DEFINE should set `-DUSE_LIBUV` and AM_CONDITIONAL should set `USE_LIBUV` as a conditional for automake.
7. If not `with_libuv != "no" && HAVE_LIBUV == 1` the preprocessor directive should not be set and the AM_CONDITIONAL should be set to `0`.

I have figured out how to do steps 1-5, but I am struggeling with 6 and 7.

Here is my current attempt:

```
AC_INIT(
  [mumble-pluginbot-plusplus],
  [0.5],
  [https://github.com/promi/mumble-pluginbot-plusplus/issues],
  [],
  [https://github.com/promi/mumble-pluginbot-plusplus])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])

AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT

# Make sure that pkg-config is installed!
# The PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro prints a horrible error message when
# pkg-config is not installed at autogen time.                   
#
# It is also required when the first PKG_CHECK_MODULES is inside a conditional
PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OPUS, [opus >= 1.1])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OPENSSL, [openssl])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(PROTOBUF, [protobuf])
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(MPDCLIENT, [libmpdclient])

AC_ARG_WITH(
  [libuv],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-libuv], [support efficient MPD status polling @<:@default=check@:>@])],
  [],
  [with_libuv=check])

# if     --with-libuv    -> it must be installed
# elseif --without-libuv -> do nothing
# else                   -> check whether it is installed
AS_CASE(
  ["$with_libuv"],
  [yes], [PKG_CHECK_MODULES(UV, [libuv >= 1.9.0], [HAVE_LIBUV=1])],
  [no],  [],
         [PKG_CHECK_MODULES(UV, [libuv >= 1.9.0], [HAVE_LIBUV=1], [HAVE_LIBUV=0])])

if test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" -eq x1; then
   AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [1])
   AC_DEFINE([USE_LIBUV], [1], [Define when libuv should be used.])
else
   AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [0])
fi

#AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([src/config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

AC_OUTPUT
```

The problematic part is this:

```
if test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" -eq x1; then
   AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [1])
   AC_DEFINE([USE_LIBUV], [1], [Define when libuv should be used.])
else
   AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [0])
fi
```

Here is an excerpt from the configure output:

```
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for OPUS... yes
checking for OPENSSL... yes
checking for PROTOBUF... yes
checking for MPDCLIENT... yes
checking for UV... yes
./configure: line 16467: test: x1: integer expression expected
./configure: line 16480: 0: command not found
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
```

How can I implement steps 6 and 7 in a way that actually works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't aborting when `yes` fails (step 3).  `AM_CONDITIONAL` [should always be run](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html).  Step 6 says `-DUSE_LIBUV`, but your existing code will add `-DUSE_LIBUV=1` to `DEFS`.  Portable shell scripting considers `test -a` [broken](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins), so you shouldn't be using that.  Your `no` case is equivalent to the `check` (or `false`) case where the search fails.

```
AS_CASE(
   ["$with_libuv"],
   [yes], [PKG_CHECK_MODULES(UV, [libuv >= 1.9.0], [HAVE_LIBUV=1],
                            [AC_MSG_ERROR("libuv >= 1.9.0 is not installed")])],
   [no],  [HAVE_LIBUV=0],
   [PKG_CHECK_MODULES(UV, [libuv >= 1.9.0], [HAVE_LIBUV=1],[HAVE_LIBUV=0])])

AS_IF([test "x$HAVE_LIBUV" = x1], [AC_DEFINE([USE_LIBUV])])
AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [test "x$HAVE_LIBUV" = x1])
```

Comment: The default action when PKG_CHECK_MODULES fails is already to abort the script, but maybe it is clearer that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `=` instead of `-eq`. The `-eq` is a relation between integers - the `x1` isn't integer!

```
if test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" -eq x1; then
```

replace to

```
if test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" = x1; then
```

Comment: That fixes the first error message (but shouldn't it be `==` then?). The other error remains, I'm checking the documentation for AM_CONDITIONAL now.

Comment: It seems like AM_CONDITIONAL can not be run inside an if statement for some reason. I will have to write the test twice.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
if test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" == x1; then
   AC_DEFINE([USE_LIBUV], [1], [Define when libuv should be used.])
fi
AM_CONDITIONAL([USE_LIBUV], [test "$with_libuv" != no -a "x$HAVE_LIBUV" == x1])
```

It's a bit ugly, because the test is executed twice, but it seems to work ok.